# Passenger Spawning a lot of Rack Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, rack

output of `passenger-memory-stats`

```
----- Passenger processes -----
PID    VMSize    Private  Name
-------------------------------
28572  207.4 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
28580  207.0 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
28588  206.0 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
28648  206.5 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
29005  23.0 MB   ?        PassengerWatchdog
29008  100.5 MB  ?        PassengerHelperAgent
29010  43.1 MB   ?        Passenger spawn server
29013  70.8 MB   ?        PassengerLoggingAgent
29053  202.0 MB  ?        Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /home/myapp/application
29105  202.3 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
29114  202.3 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
29121  202.3 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
29130  202.3 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
29138  202.3 MB  ?        Rack: /home/myapp/application
```

That looks like a lot of spawned processes... this is a app currently in development with no one (that I know of) hitting it...

the output of `passenger-status`

```
  App root: /home/myapp/application
  * PID: 29105   Sessions: 1    Processed: 0       Uptime: 15m 11s
  * PID: 29114   Sessions: 1    Processed: 0       Uptime: 14m 0s
  * PID: 29121   Sessions: 1    Processed: 0       Uptime: 14m 0s
  * PID: 29130   Sessions: 1    Processed: 0       Uptime: 14m 0s
  * PID: 29138   Sessions: 1    Processed: 0       Uptime: 14m 0s
```

First, is this normal?

Second, possible causes?

Comment: What does `passenger-status` say?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated question with output... just re-ran `passenger-memory-stats` again and it has one less Rack process

Comment: From this output, I'd say that you have hanging requests. That is, a request goes to infinite loop or whatever. So, when next request comes in, there are no spare workers and Passenger has to spawn another one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, how would you go about remedying this? is this a code issue? or a nginx+passenger issue?

Comment: When I had one of these, it was always slow database. Try to analyze your app and find out why your requests take so long.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Doh! this is my first passenger+nginx deployment and forgot to tune my max pool so I turned it down to 2 and problems went away immediately, I was Running out of RAM apparently.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having this issue of Rails hanging... If you are running on a limited memory VPS, check and make sure you tune your max_pool so that you don't spawn too many instances of the app for your system to handle.  The default is 6 which is apparently too many for memory strapped VPS's.

**Docs about max pool setting:**
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize

Answer (score 0):

It may be that some process survive from earlier versions of your app.  Our app's Rack processes each point to a specific release of our app.

95171  2491.8 MB  4.8 MB    Rack: /Deploy/theapp/releases/20120530013237

And there were multiple processes pointing to many different releases.  Which leads me to conclude these are left over when the app is restarted.

I thought may be that touching the tmp/restart.txt instead of restarting apache has this effect.  So I set :use_sudo to true, and am restarting with 'run "#{try_sudo} /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl graceful"' instead and the only Rack processes I see are those that were just started.